# Android Media Store

Tags: android

Как наверно все знают, в Android 10 представлен MediaStore для хранения и получения данных.
Я посмотрел на типы, там есть такой раздел `MediaStore.Files`. Какого формата можно туда добавлять данные?
Поддерживает ли он текстовые форматы (pdf/doc) или более сложные, например apk файлы?

Просто сомнения вызываю именно Media в названии (это обычно Image/Video/Audio)